# Using derivatives at 0 to define an inner product

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, taylor-expansion, inner-products

Can the following define an inner product on a subspace of the set of functions that are infinitely differentiable
on $[-R,R]$.
If so, do we get a Hilbert space?
$$<f, g> = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)g^{(n)}(0)}{(n!)^2} \hspace{3in}$$
The following function $f$ poses problems:

$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} e^{-1/x^2} & \mbox{if } x \neq 0\\
0 & \mbox{if } x = 0
\end{array} \right.$

This is because $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So $<f,f>  = 0$ but $f \neq 0$.  Is there a natural subspace of infinitely differentiable functions that is larger than the polynomials where this makes a good inner product?

Comment: Yes, use real-analytic functions. However, the space is likely to be incomplete.